# win32 listview inner-build scrollbar owner draw

Tags: winapi

According to msdn,message WM_NCCALCSIZE handles the non-client zone,including inner-bulid scrollbar zone.
the references of msdn make me confused.
Anyone please tell how to adjust the three rects(LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS ) to cover the inner-build scrollbar zone ?

```
    if(message==WM_NCCALCSIZE) {
    RECT rect_new;
    RECT rect_old;
    RECT client_rect_new;
    RECT client_rect_old;
    
    //adjust client rect or no-client rect
    if(wParam == TRUE) {
        LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS calc_param = (LPNCCALCSIZE_PARAMS)lParam;
        
        //before
        //0:new 1:old 2:old-client
        CopyRect(&rect_new,&(calc_param->rgrc[0]));
        CopyRect(&rect_old,&(calc_param->rgrc[1]));
        CopyRect(&client_rect_old,&(calc_param->rgrc[2]));

        //after 
        //0:new client 1:new 2:old
        client_rect_new = {rect_new.left,
                           rect_new.top,
                           rect_new.right+GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXHSCROLL),
                           rect_new.bottom+GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYHSCROLL)};
        CopyRect(&(calc_param->rgrc[0]),&client_rect_new);
        CopyRect(&(calc_param->rgrc[1]),&rect_new);
        CopyRect(&(calc_param->rgrc[2]),&rect_old);
        return WVR_VALIDRECTS;
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA3fJ.png)

Comment: You can gain some hints [here](https://github.com/jovibor/HexCtrl/blob/84d246120fd9898c316ee21fa41f67daab48cda4/HexCtrl/src/CScrollEx.cpp#L209). It's an implementation of an owner-drawn scroll bar in non client area.

Comment: What is "cover the inner-build scrollbar zone"? Can you provide more code or a sample and some screenshots to let us know what you want to achieve.

Comment: thank you @Jovibor . the MFC control shows several relevent messages 
WM_NCCALCSIZE / WM_MOUSEMOVE / WM_LBUTTONUP / WM_TIMER 
those messages according to your implementation , the re-arrange of the non-client zone   works. but the WM_LBUTTONUP message does not been triggered, don't konw why, which should stop the timer trigger ( nice way to distigwish the long press or the simple click , does not work though)

Comment: image has been posted. don't konw how to post the full code. what im doing is redrawing the inner-build scrollbar of a windows listview control.@ZhuSong-MSFT 
your name seems like we come from the same nation.

Comment: @Younth `WM_LBUTTONUP` will trigger only if `SetCapture()` was called previously, that's why `ReleaseCapture()` call in `OnLButtonUp` handler.

Comment: SetCapture() and SetFocus() all have been called , as follow your code shows. not work

Comment: Now the problem has been fixed. thank @Jovibor again. 
there is something different from your code, the handler message WM_TIMER, when deal with the countious long press timer , i add few code : GetCapture()==hwnd_ctrl , if not just killtimer directly , now it works .